# Drupal 6 form iteration through data base query

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, foreach, drupal-6

I'm trying to run a foreach over an array pulled from a db query but for some reason it isn't working. Is this a simple syntax error or something else?

```
  global $user
  $ras = db_query("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE id='%s'", $user->name); 
  $sas = db_fetch_array($ras);  
  $arr = array("one",2,3,"four",5);

  $form['questionnaire'] = array (
    '#type'=>'fieldset', 
    '#title'=> 'test', );

  foreach ($arr as $id => $value){ 
  $form['questionnaire']['fill'.$id] = array(
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=> $value,
  );
  }
```

However, the following wont work:

```
  foreach ($sas as $id => $value){ 
  $form['questionnaire']['fill'.$id] = array(
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=> $value,
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your query returns a single result, which I doubt since you're expecting an array of results, your syntax is missing something. `db_fetch_array` will only fetch one row. So you need to do something like this.

```
$form['questionnaire'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => 'test',
);

global $user;
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE id='%s'", $user->name);

// Remember that $row is an array where the key names map the column names in your table
// So if you have a column 'id' and another one 'value' you can access the
// value for one row like this $row['id] and $row['value']
while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
  $form['questionnaire']['fill' . $row['id']] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $row['column_name'],
  );
}
```

**Update 07.02.2013**: Using a `foreach()` loop instead of `while()`

```
foreach (db_fetch_array ($row) as $row) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: I'm actually looking to see how to do this with foreach. I was able to get while loop to work.

Comment: Using `while` makes more sense in this context and as you will see all over Drupal context is the way to traverse an array of rows. But if you fancy using `foreach` I've added this option as well.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks right but the obvious answer is that the query isn't returning any data.   Is it possible thst you've forgotten global $user?  Devel module can help with this.

Comment: global user not forgotten. I also used a whileloop which works. So that's why i think i got the syntax of foreach wrong